# What do you call the camera movement type in starcraft?

Tags: camera, terminology

Yeah, that's it, I cannot figure it out for the life of me.

What I'm curious about can be seen in [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=TC7BReJnGYI#t=224) (at 3:58).

Comment: What aspect of the camera movement are you talking about? Please try to describe it in a way which doesn't require to be familiar with the game.

Comment: Top-down camera? Orthographic camera?

Comment: No, the way you move the camera, that when you get close to the edges of the screen, the camera will start moving to that direction (PS.: I don't know if this technique is still used in SC2, I'm talking about SC1)

Comment: Why did this get downvoted again? Did I miss a memo or something?

Comment: It's just a plain translation of the camera. AFAIK there isn't a real name for this kind of behavior of "pushing" the camera by moving the mouse to the edge of the screen.

Comment: Your question got downvoted because it is unclear what you are asking. Your comment is also contradicting the video you posted (you wrote you are talking about SC1, but the video is from SC2), making it even less clear what you are actually talking about.

Comment: No, I said, that I'm not sure, if this still in SC2, and sorry for finding this video first over one about SC1, because it's hard to find a video, where somone even demonstrates this

Answer (score 1):

StarCraft uses a top-down camera.

Generally camera types are named based on their projection method and constraints they place on viewing the world. A top-down camera is generally called such because it always sits above the action, looking down.

The way you interact with the camera's constraints is usually less of a factor in what we call them.

StarCraft's technique of moving the camera when you get close to the screen edges is called... "moving the camera when you get close to the screen edges," or some variation on that. It does not have a standard, de-facto or otherwise, name.